# Where to upload the facebook fanpage?

Tags: facebook, facebook-page, fan-page

I am trying to upload samples of facebook fanpages on my page. I used to work with Static FBML in the past but the pages I want to upload have javascript etc so I think that they will have to be uploaded somewhere else. I am out of ideas where do professional fanpage developers upload their fanpages. I will be very thankful if you can guide me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

if you're talking about pages that you can add to a fan page it used to be fbml no they use iframes the source goes in any domain of your choice, so if you have hosting somewhere just upload your page there and copy/paste url when creating your app.  Hope this is what you are looking for.

Check [this](http://mattmoorewrites.wordpress.com/2011/02/22/how-to-set-up-facebook-iframes-apps-to-replace-fbml-on-pages/) out for more info.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are trying to do is add a custom tab to your Facebook Fan Page like I did here on mine: www.facebook.com/daterraweb

To get it done, you need to create a page and as an admin you can create a custom page tab to host it.

Basically you just need to create a document like you would for a webpage and host it at your hosting of choice and then go to: https://developers.facebook.com/apps

On the Developers apps you can create a New App each can be configured to work as a tab on the page.

I hope this helps. Good lucky.

If you still have questions about this, please check this link: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/

Comment: Thanks. I have done all the steps. I want to ask you where did you uploaded this page too?

Comment: www.daterraweb.com/facebook/daterra/index.php